# Laravel Setting User Attribute

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've googled around and searched here but for the life of me I can't work out what I'm getting wrong.

I have a tinyinteger value of '`subscribed`' value in a users table in laravel. I'm making mutator and accessor for it in the users model:

```
public function getSubscribedAttribute($value){
    return $value;
}
public function setSubscribedAttribute($value){
    //dd gives 1 if true
    //dd($value);
    $this->attributes['subscribed'] = $value;
}
```

and in a subscription controller, after subscribing the user in Stripe I call this:

```
Auth::user()->subscribed = 1;
```

In my migration

```
$table->tinyInteger('subscribed')->default(0); //0 = false, 1=true
```

Sorry if this is a dumb post, I'm really not sure what I'm not understanding here.

Comment: If I understand clear you want get subscribed value from user model, is it?

Comment: yeah, i need to get and set that field in the database, so i've made the mutators and accessors as per the laravel docs but it doesn't seem to work when doing $this->attributes part... it dd's the right value though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->subscribed = 1;
$user->save() //for change subscribed to 1
$user->subscribed //should return subscribed value from database.
```

Comment: I had no idea I had to call the save() method, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use new instance of models to change attribute you need to use save()method ;

if you want to use setXXAttribute()method ,it will be called when you use create(),insert(),update()methods.i am not sure certainly! goog luck